# STM32 USB OTG device only - not detected unless the programming USB port is also plugged in?

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-otg

I have a project based on a Nucleo H743ZI2 board that communicates with a PC through the USB OTG port on the Nucleo.
Everything is working fine as long as, weirdly enough, I have the STlink USB cabled plugged in (which I have been using to work on the firmware, flash, debug, etc).

However, today I was getting ready to do actual tests with this project and used an external power source to power the H7. I initially tried a 3.3V external source which is available from one of the shields, and then tested a lab PSU at both 3.3V. Thinking it could be PSU related I also tried external 5V with the same results.

Basically, the device is not recognized by the computer operating system, unless the STlink USB is plugged in.

I can't really put my finger on this one; I initially thought it was a PSU related issue (that nucleo board has some restrictions when it comes to using external power sources) but at this point I am fairly confident I am failing to initialize something in my code. Not sure what though.

I'd be happy to share with my code, but wouldn't know where the start. I haven't done much as far as the USB OTG is concerned other than modifying the receive callback to process the data.

Any idea what I might be missing here?

Cheers

Comment: Aside from PSU issues, I can image two more reasons: 1) USB is unresponsive because firmware has crashed. Do you have a indicating that the firmware is running ? 2) Computer thinks that your board is in USB host role. Is the USB ID pin floating?

Comment: semihosting would also stop the program if not debugger is attached.

Comment: Yes I have indications that the firmware is running (couple debug LED's). As for the ID pin, only D+ and D- are setup in cubeMX, so it is my understanding that the ID should be floating, yes. @Piglet not sure what semihosting is

Comment: just google it. you basically redirect your printf's to your pc through your debugger. something you can do if you don't have usart available.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the source of the problem : your code crash somewhere trying to send info to the debugger.